# Fill a empty value of a key-value pair using the next value

Tags: javascript, typescript

Fill a empty value of a key-value pair with the next value of the next key.

```
myitems = {
 'items1': [{first:true, second:false}, {first:true, second:true}],
 'items2': [], //should be filled with {first:true, second:false}
 'items3': [], //should be filled with {first:true, second:false}
 'items4': [{first:true, second:false}, {first:true, second:true}],
 'items5': [{first:false, second:true}],
 'items6': [], //should be filled with {first:true, second:true}
 'items7': [{first:true, second:true}],
}
```

I have tried the follow:

```
Object.entries(myItems).forEach(([key, value], index, values: any) => {
   if (!values[index][1].length && values[index+1] && values[index+1][1].length) {
   myItems[key] = [{...values[index + 1][1][0]}]
 }
})
```

Comment: Can you explain why items2 and items3 need to be filled with those values?

Comment: Also, what if - i.e: `"items7"` (or any last one) has an empty array? - I really think you did not thought out your problem here.

Comment: @technophyle, if it is a empty value it should have the first value of the next key.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, the last key have allways a value.

Comment: @Mat in such odd case can you explain what you're actually doing? This starts to seem like an XY-Problem

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan,I want to guarantee a continuation between items, this continuation is guaranteed with the first value of the next available item. Look at this as an interpolation, but I don't want the "intermediate value", I want the "final value".

Comment: @Mat well, then using an Object instead of an Array or Map to store your *items* is your first issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific example, an idea could be to use a temporary `next` variable that stores the last known next's Object from the Array of `Object.values`, and use .reduceRight() or .reverse().forEach():

```js
const myItems = {
  'items1': [{first:true, second:false}, {first:true, second:true}],
  'items2': [], //should be filled with {first:true, second:false}
  'items3': [], //should be filled with {first:true, second:false}
  'items4': [{first:true, second:false}, {first:true, second:true}],
  'items5': [{first:false, second:true}],
  'items6': [], //should be filled with {first:true, second:true}
  'items7': [{first:true, second:true}],
};


let next;
Object.values(myItems).reverse().forEach((arr, i) => {
  if (!i || arr.length) return next = arr[0];
  arr[0] = {...next};
});

console.log(myItems);
```

But again this is a really bad idea.

Comment: In older version of js property order could not be guaranteed but in modern EMCA JS there is a spec for order - <i>The traversal order, as of modern ECMAScript specification, is well-defined and consistent across implementations. Within each component of the prototype chain, all non-negative integer keys (those that can be array indices) will be traversed first in ascending order by value, then other string keys in ascending chronological order of property creation.</i>

Answer (score 1):

You should listen to the comments about the order of the keys in the object... But maybe the `reduceRight` method will help you somehow:

```js
const myItems = {
  'items1': [{first:false, second:false}, {first:false, second:false}],
  'items2': [], //should be filled with {first:true, second:false}
  'items3': [], //should be filled with {first:true, second:false}
  'items4': [{first:true, second:false}, {first:true, second:true}],
  'items5': [{first:false, second:true}],
  'items6': [], //should be filled with {first:true, second:true}
  'items7': [{first:true, second:true}],
}

const result = Object.entries(myItems).reduceRight( (accumulator, currentValue) => {
  const [key, value] = currentValue;
  if (!value.length) {
    accumulator.unshift([key, [...accumulator[0][1]]]);
  } else {
    accumulator.unshift([key, [...value]]);
  }
  return accumulator;
}, [] );

console.log( JSON.stringify( Object.fromEntries(result), null, 2 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the data object as you posted it, the order IS guaranteed.
Here is a solution in TypeScript

```
const myItems: Record<string,{first:boolean, second:boolean}[]> = {
 'items1': [{first:true, second:false}, {first:true, second:true}],
 'items2': [], //should be filled with {first:true, second:false}
 'items3': [], //should be filled with {first:true, second:false}
 'items4': [{first:true, second:false}, {first:true, second:true}],
 'items5': [{first:false, second:true}],
 'items6': [], //should be filled with {first:true, second:true}
 'items7': [{first:true, second:true}],
}

const arr: (keyof typeof myItems)[] =[];
for (let k in myItems) arr.push(k);
arr.reverse();
console.log(arr);
let last: {first:boolean, second:boolean} | undefined;
arr.forEach((k,ki)=>{
    if (myItems[k].length===0){
        if (last) myItems[k].push(last);
    }
    else {
        last = myItems[k][0];
    }
});
for (let k in myItems) {
    console.log(k);
    console.log(myItems[k][0]);
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-LFY2oAba5ja6hZuotLXM13VOLW4XZBX5NzexppAaIwLbSKxS3JUPaziTWaLUq55md7w95aN-mpzODZiNEA)

The output is

```
[LOG]: ["items7", "items6", "items5", "items4", "items3", "items2", "items1"] 
[LOG]: "items1" 
[LOG]: {
  "first": true,
  "second": false
} 
[LOG]: "items2" 
[LOG]: {
  "first": true,
  "second": false
} 
[LOG]: "items3" 
[LOG]: {
  "first": true,
  "second": false
} 
[LOG]: "items4" 
[LOG]: {
  "first": true,
  "second": false
} 
[LOG]: "items5" 
[LOG]: {
  "first": false,
  "second": true
} 
[LOG]: "items6" 
[LOG]: {
  "first": true,
  "second": true
} 
[LOG]: "items7" 
[LOG]: {
  "first": true,
  "second": true
}
```

Here is the [relevant MDN documentation on object property order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#description)

> The traversal order, as of modern ECMAScript specification, is well-defined and consistent across implementations. Within each component of the prototype chain, all non-negative integer keys (those that can be array indices) will be traversed first in ascending order by value, then other string keys in ascending chronological order of property creation.

Note: If `myItems` final properties are empty arrays then they stay as empty arrays because there is nothing to set them with.